# Is there a C# equivalent to python's type() function?

Tags: c#, python, types

I am learning `C#` and have a very basic background in `Python` where I was familiar with the [type() function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) where the data type of a variable can be returned via:

`type(myVariable)`

Is there a `C#` equivalent to this function?

I am asking in the context of wanting to use such a function on a C# variable that has been created using `var` eg:

`var myNewVariable = "Hello!"`

I am using explicit data types in general eg:

`string myNewString = "Hello!"`

But I am just wondering what data type a variable created using `var` defaults to and thought something similar to `type()` would be a good way to check out what was happening '**under the hood**` so to speak.

Comment: `myNewVariable.GetType()`

Comment: `.GetType()` will tell you the runtime type, but the compiler can tell you what the variable's type is.

Comment: Side note: If you have ReSharper installed it has way to convert between `var` and explicit type...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try using [*GetType()*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) method:

```
Type myType = myVariable.GetType();
```

For instance

```
String typeName = "My String".GetType().Name; // <- "String"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have couple of options here

1. typeof. typeof takes a type name (which you specify at compile time).
2. GetType gets the runtime type of an instance.

Example

```
B a = new B();
a.GetType() == typeof(B)
```

Note: **a** is an instance of an object **B**. Whereas B is a type.